# Can Message Broker 7.0 running on z/OS extract/update SQL Server data?

Tags: messagebroker, message-bus

Need your inputs around how to extract and update data from SQL Server 2012 database from Message Broker V7.0 running on Z/OS. We initially thought of using Database Input Node of MB. But as MB 7 on z/OS doesn't seem to support SQL Server as per IBM 7.0 info center (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ah10030_.htm), would there have to be some custom code / custom node to connect to SQL Server?

Any Ideas around this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect from zOS to SQLServer using the JDBC APIs but not the ODBC ones. So I'd be looking at using JCN's with the managed JDBC conenction API here.